# Why changing $scope variable does not show element with ng-show in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, video

I'm developing a simple site with a video.

Here is a plunker with the code of my page: http://plnkr.co/edit/5NUnZ2KET1apWwxMxjex?p=preview

I have a video on my site, with the html5 tag `video` you can play and pause it.

When the video is played or stopped, a play icon is show/hide with a `$scope` variable

```
<label ng-click="video()" ng-show="!playing" class="playButton"></label>
```

This is the function that plays and pauses the video:

```
$scope.video = function() {
    if(!$scope.playing)
    {
        video.play();
        $scope.playing = true;
        video.onended = function() {
            $scope.playing = false;
            alert(1);
        };
    }
    else
    {
        video.pause();
        $scope.playing = false;
    }
}
```

The alert is being shown when the video is done, so the event is triggering correctly. There is something wrong in the way I change the value of `playing` variable.

Comment: Seems to work for me. Play button appears and disappears as expected.

Comment: Not when the video ends, the alert is show, the button stil hidden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code inside

```
video.onended = function() {
    // body
};
```

Is executed outside of [digest cycle](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle) and because of that angular has no way of knowing that the `$scope.playing` has changed.

One way to solve it is to change the function to

```
video.onended = function() {
   $scope.$apply(function(){
      //body
   });
};
```

I've updated your [sample accordingly](http://plnkr.co/edit/pmvFMwFW6lULB7tylidm?p=preview).